# How to find out what the bitrate is of my audio file?

Tags: audio, ogg, bitrate

I wondered how I could find out what the bitrate is of my ogg audio file?

My Operating System is Windows 7 32 bit, if that would make any difference.

Comment: You might edit you original question to include your Operating System.

Comment: Ok, I edited it.

Comment: Have you tried using VLC http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ which I think shows the bitrate of a given audio file within the properties.

Comment: @Aaron It may well show it , but I don't even see a properties option in VLC.

Comment: Have you actually found it or have you just accepted an answer before you tested it? I just tried playing a file in VLC, it said 1.00x while playing, so if Andrei Duma is right then I suppose that'd be the bitrate, but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented above, most audio players specify the bit rate at play time. Try VLC.

EDIT: Well, not really at play time; you have to "CTRL+J" to see it. See below.

@barlop

Here are 2 screenshots:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I guess, that's the bitrate?

Comment: Why don't you say where in VLC?

Comment: That only works for audio files, not for streaming audio, right?  The question is about streaming audio.  In Virtual DJ it shows what bitrate is available, but it might stream a lower bitrate on my rural internet.

Answer (score 0):

From my test, VLC doesn't show bitrate while playing(at least not by default in the playing window) and i'm not sure where it'd show it.

However, Windows XP does(and no doubt vista and 7). In XP you move the mouse over the filename and that popup comes up and says the bitrate.

[image]

Comment: that move over with mouse does not work with ogg files since Windows does not have support for ogg files.

Comment: ah ok.. I see.  btw, an interesting note.. VLC doesn't seem to show bitrate of wmv or so it seems.. tools..codec information.. bits per sample 16. but windows "hovering" does show for wmv.

Comment: If you install the [Ogg DirectShow Filters](http://xiph.org/dshow/) then Explorer should show the information.

Comment: @afrazier The DirectShow Filters for OGG don't solve the problem (on Windows 7).

Comment: @barlop I reposted my comment according to your suggestion an deleted the old ones. Feel free to delete yours as well, so that the comments are clean and on-topic.